# How to show an image icon on a particular display tag header?

Tags: html, css, jsp, displaytag

I am using `Display Tag` library for pagination and sorting.I am also adding some icon images (upArrow,downArrow) next to the table header so that when a user clicks on a header field to sort the columns the images will  show up according to the ordering criteria. Initially the icon won't be in any of the header column but I want it in my `created date` column when the page loads up as default just to let the users know that the column has been sorted (I am not sure how can I achieve this).

Once the user clicks on one field the icon form the previous field disappears and appears on the selected columns(This is done).

Columns on startup (no arrow icons, but I need to show it on the Created date column)
[image]

After user clicks on the E-Sign Created Date column (icon appears)
[image]

How can I show the icon on the created date column when the page loads up?

JSP:

```
<display:table id="data" name="intgList" requestURI="/integration/viewIntegration" class="fieldLabelCell" pagesize="10">
        <!-- Setting table properties -->
        <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true"/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="top"/>
        <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list_row" value=""/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="2"/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.no_items_found" value=""/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.page.separator" value=" of "/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks"> |< << | Page {0} <a href="{3}"> | >> </a><a href="{4}">>|</a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}">|< </a> <a href="{2}"> << | Page </a> {0} | >> >| </span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}">|< </a> <a href="{2}"> << | Page </a> {0}<a href="{3}"> | >> </a><a href="{4}">>| </a></span>'/>

        <!-- Displaying columns data -->
        <display:column property="lob" title="Line of<br>Business" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="insuredName" title="Insured" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns"/>
        <display:column property="custPhone" title="Customer<br>Phone" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="policyNumber" title="Policy #" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="createdDate" title="E-Sign<br>Created Date" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="custEmail" title="Customer<br>Email" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column title="# of E-Sign Documents" class="displayColumns" >
            <c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
                <a id="eSignNumDocs" href= "javascript:locateFunc('viewESignDetails', {'url':'<integration:urlAction actionName="/integration/viewDetailsIntegration"><integration:urlParam key="esignIdentifier" value="${list.esignId}"/></integration:urlAction>',
                    'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                    'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                    'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                    'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                    'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                    'lob':'${list.lob}',
                    'transId':'${list.transId}',
                    'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                    'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                    'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                    'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'});">
                    <c:out value="${list.esignNumDocs}"/>
                </a>
            </c:forEach>
        </display:column>
    </display:table>
```

CSS:

```
th {
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

th.order1 {
background: url("../images/integration/upArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
} 

th.order2 {
background: url("../images/integration/downArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am doing it using CSS and it is working perfectly fine.

```
th {
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

th:nth-child(5) {
background: url("../images/integration/downArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
}

th.order1 {
background: url("../images/integration/upArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
} 

th.order2 {
background: url("../images/integration/downArrow.gif") no-repeat 30%;
}
```